# ogr2ogr: issue with batch clipping shapefiles with converted kml file as clip source

Tags: ogr2ogr

I wrote this script that (running in MSYS) converts a kml to shp and applies a re-projection to it. The resulting shp then has the same SRS as the shps that I want to clip with it. I use a for loop to look up the shp files in a certain folder and then want to apply the clipping.
The conversion throws some neglectable (?) warnings and yields a working shp-file.

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'description' to 'descriptio'
Warning 6: Field timestamp create as date field, though DateTime requested.
Warning 6: Field begin create as date field, though DateTime requested.
Warning 6: Field end create as date field, though DateTime requested.
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'altitudeMode' to 'altitudeMo'
```

However, the second part is not working (no errors, just the ogr2ogr usage infos as it appears if there are syntactical errors)

```
cd D:/GIS_DataBase/GIS_Tirol/Scharnitz

outdir=D:/GIS_DataBase/GIS_Tirol/Scharnitz/Data
indir=D:/GIS_DataBase/GIS_Tirol/Tirol_Verbreitungskarten/Verbreitungs_Daten

mkdir outdir

# reproject and convert clipsource to desired SRS and shpfile-format
ogr2ogr -overwrite -skipfailures -append -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs EPSG:31254 clpsrcfile.shp scharnitz_gem_grenze.kml

# clip all files in indir and save to outdir
for x in $indir/*.shp
  do ogrinfo -al $x | grep Extent
  ls $x
  ogr2ogr -clpsrc clpsrcfile.shp $outdir $x
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first script, several of the warnings are related to the maximum number of characters (10) allowed in a [shapefile dbf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_attribute_format_.28.dbf.29). This is not an issue per say but be careful with large attribute names that will be truncated & be difficult to know what they mean.

In the second part, you are calling ogr2ogr incorrectly to clip. Need to specify the output shapefile to be created (clipped points in my case), followed by the input to be clipped. clip feature is specified by -clipsrc.
Have a look over the [ogr2ogr document here](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), note the "dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name".

Call should like this for single clip:

```
ogr2ogr clipped_2.shp points.shp -clipsrc region.shp
```